# CREATE KEYSPACE using Cassandra builder

Tags: java, cassandra

Instead of hard cording schema, I am trying to build using Cassandra API. My schema is

"CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS"

Example, for creating table we are using

SchemaBuilder.createTable(tableName).ifNotExists();

Same way how to create 'KEYSPACE'?

I am using Cassandra 3.x version.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The `com.datastax.oss.driver.api.querybuilder.SchemaBuilder` API provides `SchemaBuilder.createTable("<keyspace>", "<tableName>")` in one shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
SchemaBuilder.createKeyspace(keyspaceName).ifNotExists()
```

[Cassandra-Java API DOC](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.1/com/datastax/driver/core/schemabuilder/class-use/CreateKeyspace.html)

Comment: Thanks Anshul. But I already tried with **createKeyspace** method. Surprise, it is telling method is undefined. I checked  SchemaBuilder binary, but this method has not defined there.

Comment: After investigation I come to know, I am using **Cassandra 3.0**  and this method has defined above Cassandra 3.0. Once again thanks Anshul.